# Can Tanjiro See The Dead?

Tags: demon-slayer

In the first few episodes of Demon Slayer as Tanjiro trains he sees 2 dead apprentice Demon Slayers, Sabito & Makomo. I was wondering if Tanjiro had some sort of ability that connects him to the dead or the reason behind him being able to see the ghosts.
So can Tanjiro see the dead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is Tanjiro able to talk to the souls?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55276/how-is-tanjiro-able-to-talk-to-the-souls)

Answer (score 0):

He had the opportunity to talk to many souls (or ghosts if you want to put it that way) yes, but it was never officially stated in the manga if he can see the dead. We can safely assume he had those interactions because the souls wanted to. Same is the case with the other characters in Demon Slayer.